# What is the built-in way to ensure Python3.x doesn't implicitly convert bytes to other class when indexing lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In writing a set of Python scripts to parse TLV data from Decawave DWM1001 modules, I'm encountering a cases where the return type of a function changes when I request one vs. more than one elements from a list of bytes.  I think the problem is that the syntax I am using permits Python to automatically cast the bytes data into a type it assumes will be more useful to me.  This causes the calling function, which expects data in the form of bytes, to break when trying to convert from bytes to int, or to string, etc.

I have been hacking through it on a case-by-case basis with conditional statements, but it's starting to make my code unnecessarily hard to read.  I would really rather correct my bad syntax understanding.

Here is simplified example:

```
>>> buffer = bytes([1,2,3,4])
>>> buffer[0:1]
'\x01'
>>> type(_)
<class 'bytes' >
>>> buffer[0]  # Expected identical output as above
1
>>> type(_)
<class 'int'>
```

Why are the outputs not identical?  I know that I can use isinstance() to check if a return value is a byte before trying to convert it from a byte to something else, but I have seen advice that I agree with that this can create fragility in the code that may cause problems if someone builds on my work.

What is the built-in way to ensure Python3.x doesn't implicitly convert bytes to other class when indexing lists?

[Edit: I see that using the colon happens to get me the result I want this time, but I don't understand why, and because I don't know why, I don't trust it not to break later.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range `[x:y]` returns always same type, it's naturally sublist/subbytes.
[x] is then individual array item. bytes is list of byte vales (which is simply int)

List of int behaves is same way

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0:1] 
[1]
>>> a[0]
1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm puzzled that bytes behave this way instead of the way  a simple 8-bit character in C would, but after testing it a bit, I see that if I treat "bytes" as "list of ints" then what I've been observing makes sense.